# Action on one pandas dataframe does the same to the one it was copied from

Tags: python, pandas

I was using this bit of code (re-worked for my application) when I found that the `df_temp.drop(index=sample.index, inplace=True)` performed the same action on df_input i.e. it emptied it!!! I was not expecting that at all.

I solved it by changing `df_temp = df_input` to `df_temp = df_input.copy()` but can someone illuminate me on what is going on here?

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df_input = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')

df = df_input.loc[[]]
df_temp = df_input # this is where we're sampling from
n_samples = 1000
for _ in range(n_samples):
    sample = df_temp.sample(1)
    df_temp.drop(index=sample.index, inplace=True)
    df = df.append(sample)

assert((df.index.value_counts() > 1).sum() == 0)
df
```

Comment: What is this line doing here? df = df_input.loc[[]]. Are you trying to locate anything from the dataframe?

Comment: It’s not my code - it was just their way of making an empty copy of the data frame - works ok!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas does not copy the whole df if you simply assign it to a new variable. After executing `df_temp = df_input` you end up with two variables referring to the exact same df. It's not the case that both are referring to an identical df, they are actually pointing to the same df. (think: you just gave this one df two names (variable names)) So no matter which variable (think: name) you are using to alter the df you're also changing for the other variable. If you use `.copy()` you get what you intended, namely two variables with two distinct versions of the df.

Comment: Thank you - I understand your answer but this is not very intuitive. I would have thought it would just make a copy but then why have .copy()… You could get seriously tripped up by this